# Can't comment code in phpStorm using cmd+/ if selected code is right after php opening tag

Tags: phpstorm, comments, keymapping

I am having an annoying problem and I don't know if this is the default behavior or if I did something wrong (maybe accidentally changed some configuration values?).

When I am trying to comment code using keys cmd+/ and cursor is (or selection begins) on the code line right after opening php tag, nothing happens (see screenshot below)

[image: selecting and commenting code this way does not work]

but if I move cursor (or start of selection) by one line, commenting code with cmd+/ works fine (see screenshot below).

[image: selecting code this way does work]

Am I missing something, could anyone confirm this behavior or maybe someone knows a solution to this annoying problem?

I am using phpStorm 7.1 (Build #PS-133.982) on Mac OS 10.9.2

By the way Cmd+Alt+/ works fine on both cases, but it creates block comment, not line comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can confirm this behaviour on 7.1.3 on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

But it works just fine in **v8 EAP** build 136.1255

You can try EAP build yourself (you can run it alongside with v7 -- just not the same project in both IDEs at the same time) -- http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm